# PHP Call a class from within a static function

Tags: php, class, static

I need to use a PHP class that I need to use inside multiple static functions of another class.

What is the correct way to create an instance of a class to be used by a static functions in a PHP class?

I have tried instantiating the class outside the class.

```
<?php

$newClassInstance = new importedClass();
$newClassInstance->init();

Class Foo{
    public static function fooMatic(){
        $newClassInstance->doStuff();
    }
}
?>
```

With this error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION
```

... Inside each funciton:

```
Class Foo{
    public static function fooMatic(){

        $newClassInstance = new importedClass();
        $newClassInstance->init();

        $newClassInstance->doStuff();
    }
}
?>
```

Error:

```
Call to a member function doStuff() on a non-object
```

And before all the functions:

```
<?php

Class Foo{

    $newClassInstance = new importedClass();
    $newClassInstance->init();

    public static function fooMatic(){

        $newClassInstance->doStuff();
    }
}
?>
```

Error:

```
syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION
```

Comment: show the exact error message please

Comment: There is only a single one that actually works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not pass the class instance via a parameter?

```
class Foo{
    public static function fooMatic($classInstance){
        $classInstance->doStuff();
    }
}
```

Then you can call it this way:

```
$newClassInstance = new importedClass();
$newClassInstance->init();
Foo::fooMatic($newClassInstance);
```